# PySpark: modify column values when another column value satisfies a condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark Dataframe with two columns:

```
+---+----+
| Id|Rank|
+---+----+
|  a|   5|
|  b|   7|
|  c|   8|
|  d|   1|
+---+----+
```

For each row, I'm looking to replace `Id` column with "other" if `Rank` column is larger than 5.

If I use pseudocode to explain:

```
For row in df:
  if row.Rank > 5:
     then replace(row.Id, "other")
```

The result should look like this:

```
+-----+----+
|   Id|Rank|
+-----+----+
|    a|   5|
|other|   7|
|other|   8|
|    d|   1|
+-----+----+
```

Any clue how to achieve this? Thanks!!!

---

To create this Dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('a', 5), ('b', 7), ('c', 8), ('d', 1)], ['Id', 'Rank'])
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use `when` and `otherwise` like -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df\
.withColumn('Id_New',when(df.Rank <= 5,df.Id).otherwise('other'))\
.drop(df.Id)\
.select(col('Id_New').alias('Id'),col('Rank'))\
.show()
```

this gives output as -

```
+-----+----+
|   Id|Rank|
+-----+----+
|    a|   5|
|other|   7|
|other|   8|
|    d|   1|
+-----+----+
```

Comment: nice one @Pushkr!

Comment: @titiro89 Yours is a clear solution to explain the usage of RDD and map! Thanks!  It works on this exemplar, but on my real data set the "a = df.rdd" operation incurred a bunch of tasks and failed at last. Not sure if it's expensive to change from df to RDD.

Answer (score 19):

Starting with @Pushkr solution couldn't you just use the following ?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('Id',when(df.Rank <= 5,df.Id).otherwise('other')).show()
```