# Update Pyspark rows for a column based on other column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `data frame` in `pyspark` like below.

```
df.show()
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  1| sam|
|  2| Tim|
|  3| Jim|
|  4| sam|
+---+----+
```

Now I added a new column to the `df` like below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
new_df = df.withColumn('new_column', lit(None).cast(StringType()))
```

Now when I query the `new_df`

```
new_df.show()
+---+----+----------+
| id|name|new_column|
+---+----+----------+
|  1| sam|      null|
|  2| Tim|      null|
|  3| Jim|      null|
|  4| sam|      null|
+---+----+----------+
```

Now I want to update the value in `new_column` based on a condition.

I am trying to write the below condition but unable to do so.

if `name` is `sam` then `new_column` should be `tested` else `not_tested`

```
if name == sam:
    then update new_column to tested
else:
    new_column == not_tested
```

How can I achieve this in `pyspark`.

> Edit 
>   I am not looking for a if else statement but how to update the values of a record in `pyspark` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user9367133 Thank you for reaching out, if you follow my answer on [similiar question you pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988801/pyspark-modify-column-values-when-another-column-value-satisfies-a-condition/43990912?noredirect=1#comment87307900_43990912) , its pretty much same logic -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

new_df\
.drop(new_df.new_column)\
.withColumn('new_column',when(new_df.name == "sam","tested").otherwise('not_tested'))\
.show()
```

You dont necessarily have to add new_column before hand as null if you are just going to replace with proper values immediately. But I wasnt sure about use case, so I kept it in my example.

hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: How can I include two string comparison, in `when(new_df.name == "sam","tested")` . I tried `when(new_df.name == "sam" or "Tim","tested")` it gives me error

Comment: look up `isin()` api